# How do you show that orbits of $f(x)=x-x^3$ converge to $0$ for$-\sqrt{2} < x < \sqrt{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, dynamical-systems

It is easy to show when $0\leq|x|\leq1$, but for values of $1<|x|<\sqrt{2}$, I have a hard time showing that $|f(x_{0})| < |x_{0}|$.

I am pretty sure I just have to show that eventually $|f^n(x_{0})| \leq 1$ but I am stuck.

Comment: Maybe you could show that either the sign changes every time or stays the same every time in this interval, and then compare without the absolute values on that basis?

Comment: Can you show your work for determining when $ |x - x^3 | < |x| $? I'm wondering where/why you are stuck. (Note that this isn't sufficient as ye to prove the original statement.)

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "orbit of $f$"?

Answer (score 0):

For only the statement in the body, that $|x|\in(1,\sqrt 2)\to |f(x)|\lt |x|,$ note that $|x|\gt 1\to |x^3|\gt |x|\to \frac{|x-x^3|}{x-x^3}=-\frac{|x|}x.$

Since we wish to show that $|f(x)|\lt |x|,$ note the sign swap over the interval of interest from above and use the inequality $x^3-x\lt x$ with positive $x$ and $x-x^3\lt -x$ with negative $x.$  This is true when $x^3\lt 2x$ (positive) and $2x\lt x^3$ (negative) which are both true for all $|x|$ in our interval.

But take caution as this particular inequality does not prove the result that $f^n(x_0)\to 0$ for $x_0\in(-\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2).$